# Tmux: binding Ctrl-`

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

I'd like to bind Ctrl-` in tmux to select-pane.

I've tried:
bind -n C-` select-pane -t :.+
Which gives me: unknown key C-`

I've also tried:
bind -n 'C-`' select-pane -t :.+
Which gives me the same error.

I then tried just plain `:
bind -n ` select-pane -t :.+
That worked fine (but bound ` not C-`.

Most confusingly, I tried:
bind -n `-C select-pane -t :.+
Which surprisingly worked (I had to hit backtick first, and then ctrl). What is it within Ctrl-` that tmux doesn't like?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`tmux` uses this logic for handling the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> modifier in `key-string.c` (backtick is code 96):

```
    /* Convert the standard control keys. */                               
    if (key < KEYC_BASE && (modifiers & KEYC_CTRL) && !strchr(other, key)) {
            if (key >= 97 && key <= 122)
                    key -= 96;
            else if (key >= 64 && key <= 95)
                    key -= 64;
            else if (key == 32)
                    key = 0;
            else if (key == 63)
                    key = KEYC_BSPACE;
            else
                    return (KEYC_NONE);
            modifiers &= ~KEYC_CTRL;
    }
```

Although some applications may treat the whole range from 64 to 126 as valid for <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, tmux excludes backtic, curly braces, vertical bar and tilde.  The likely reason is that they are less useful for key bindings because the unmodified keys are often used in shell scripts.

On the other hand, `ctrl-@` would have the same expected interpretation, and you could use that instead.

Comment: I've tried C-@ and that didn't work (It selected panes with Ctrl+@ but not with Ctrl+`) :(

Comment: But as one can see (reading the source code), tmux does not do what was requested, unless you modify the program.

Answer (score 6):

I found somewhere the advice to use `cat` inside tmux to check escape sequence.

1. Run `tmux`
2. Run `cat`
3. Press keys `` C-` ``

On my terminal I've got `^@`

So in the config I've put

`set -g prefix ^@`

Worked for me with `roxterm`

Comment: `^@` works well with tilix